# Creating a new Ionic project through Ionic CLI suddenly started producing npm/git errors

Tags: node.js, git, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I started learning Ionic 2/3 a couple of days ago and have created some demo projects as well by following tutorials. Now, I tried creating a new project again but this error suddenly started to appear. I tried searching as to why this is happening but all I found were just some vague answers or unrelated ones.

`npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys`

[image]

Some answers suggested downgrading my NPM but I don't think that's the right way to resolve this as I haven't done any updating.

Comment: create blank project using   "ionic start project_name blank --v2 ". I am sure it will not return any error

Comment: @KishoreKumar, "--v2" is already deprecated.

Comment: use ionic start myApp tabs

Comment: @KishoreKumar, simply doing `ionic start` already causes this problem.

Comment: Follow this step again, i am sure this will help you 1) npm install -g cordova ionic
2) ionic start myApp blank
3) cd myApp
4) ionic serve

Comment: @KishoreKumar, I have tried that multiple times already.

Comment: I face same problem. First uninstall `object-keys`. Then run `npm install -g object-keys`